# Does calling functions that are just redefined require polymorphism?

Tags: c++, binding, polymorphism, redefinition

How would C++ tell which definition of a redefined function (excluding virtual functions) to execute if it doesn't do some sort of binding? If it does binding for functions that are just redefined, is it static or dynamic binding?

```cpp
class Base {

public:
void display() {
   std::cout << "BASE";
}

};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
void display() {
   std::cout << "DERIVED";
}
};
```

Comment: Non-virtual functions are statically bound.

Comment: Your question is meaningless. It is same as asking "does controlling organization by the majority of its members require democracy?"

Comment: Are you familiar with function overloading? Your question is quite unclear. Do you have a short code example that you're confused by?

Comment: @alterigel I know that overloading requires static binding. But, function re-definitions don't require overloading, so I was curious as to what sort of binding occurs since redefined functions don't require dynamic binding either.

Comment: You cannot redefine a function

Comment: @CAPITANCHURO are you referring to class member functions? Again, can you [edit] your post and show a short code example that highlights what you would like to know?

Comment: @alterigel Yes. I don't think redefining is used in any other context other than within the context of a hierarchy tree.

Comment: @CAPITANCHURO thank you for the edit, it adds a huge amount of clarity. Are you familiar with `virtual` functions?